# Selecting odd values using tkinter Scale

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to select only the odd values **(1,3,5,7...)** using `Tkinter.Scale`. I tried using:

```
tk.Scale(top,variable = scalevar,from_=1,to_=10,\
     resolution = 2,length = 400, takefocus = 1, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
```

But this is giving me a scale bar starting from value **2** instead of **1**.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* always build a helper function to correct the input.

I made a sample script to demonstrate:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
past = 1
def fix(n):
    global past
    n = int(n)
    if not n % 2:
        scale.set(n+1 if n > past else n-1)
        past = scale.get()
scale = tk.Scale(from_=1, to_=9, command=fix, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
scale.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

This counts by odd numbers like you wanted, only it uses the function `fix` to explicitly set the input to an odd number.

You need the `past` variable to determine whether the scale is being incremented or decremented.
If `n > past`, the scale is being incremented.  So, the function sets the scale forward.
If `n < past`, the scale is being decremented.  So, the function sets the scale back.

I'll admit this is somewhat of a hack, but it should work for you.

Comment: Well this seems to work, but is a bit buggy! If I slide the slider, I can get it to even values too.

Comment: @user1599497 - Right.  In an attempt to condense the code, I accidentally removed a line I needed. :*)  That sliding bug should be fixed now.  Like I said, this is kinda a hack.  The best solution would be to do as you said and patch `tkScale.c` if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed. @xndrme : Though I would have liked to fix "txScale.c" but I was not able to locate it in ubuntu 12.04. So I guess this is what I would be using for now. But thanks still. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, that seems like a bug in **Tk** in the file **tkScale.c**, you can read [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14628) about that, the bug report is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tktoolkit/bugs/2411/).

Comment: So I guess I need to patch tkScale.c. Any idea where I can locate this file? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `resolution=2` and add `tickinterval=2`. Everything else should be fine.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants.  He wants the scale to count by odd numbers.  In other words, a scale with no even numbers.

Comment: This gives me ticks, and the variable (scalevar) returns all values both even and odd. I need the variable to return only odd values.